# merging data frames while assigning factors to missing data

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have two data frames that have overlap between samples (df1 and df2).  I want to create a new data frame (df3) from these while assigning "absent" (a factor) to the samples in df1 that are not present in df2. I then create a 4th data frame to do an outer join on df2 and df3.

I have figured out a very long way to do this, but would appreciate suggestions on how to make this code more succinct.

```
Sample <- c("TG1","TG2","TG3","TG4","TG5","TG6","TG7","TG8","TG9","TG10")
blaOKP <- c(rep("-",10))
tet.B <- c(rep("-", 10))
df1<- data.frame(Sample,blaOKP,tet.B)

Sample <- c("TG1","TG4","TG8")
gyrA <- c(rep("T83I",3))
gyrB <- c(rep("D87N",3))
df2 <- data.frame(Sample,gyrA,gyrB)

df3 <- df1[-which(df1$Sample %in% df2$Sample),]
df3$gyrA <- "absent"
df3$gyrB <- "absent"
df3 <- df3[,c(1,3:5)]


require(plyr)
df4 <- join(x=df2, y=df3, by="Sample", type="full")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to get the result similar to "df4" (ordered by "Sample" column).  This would be faster for big datasets.  Convert the "df1" to `data.table` by `setDT` and set the key variable as "Sample" (`setkey`).  Then join the "df2" with "df1" after removing the 2nd column ("blaOKP") as it was not in the "df4".  Assign the "tet.B" column to "NA", then assign columns "2:4" with "absent" and "-" for those rows that are "NA" in "gyrA"

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df2), Sample)[df1[-2]][, 
       tet.B := NA_character_][is.na(gyrA),
         2:4 := list('absent', 'absent', '-')][]
```

Answer (score 2):

Joining conventions in `dplyr` is illustrated nicely [here](https://twitter.com/yutannihilation/status/551572539697143808).

```
anti_join(df1,df2, by="Sample") %>% 
  mutate(gyrA="absent", gyrB="absent") %>% 
  full_join(df2, by="Sample")
```

Comment: That's nice (never heard of `anti_join`) but you still need to accomplish `df4` output

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Recently `dplyr` got updated with more functions `bind_rows`, `bind_cols`. Now `rbind_list` etc are deprecated...

Comment: This is a nice easy way to do it.  I'm interested in learning dplyr.  Can you suggest an tutorials or resources?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, also interested about df4 output.  You can always do a full join of df2 and df3, but not sure if there is an easier way?